# COUNTIF to count =TODAY()

Tags: excel, countif

In Excel I am using DDE to pull intraday stock quote information. So it is continuously updating. I am trying to:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"="&TODAY())
```

But the column A:A which are dates some not of current date. Are being produced by functions or forumlas so they are not being read as text. I don't want to change the column into text so it can be read. because it refreshes every minute.

Is there a way to get `=COUNTIF(A:A,"="&TODAY())` to read the text that is being produced by the functions within A:A instead of the functions?

Comment: Whether the dates in column A are text or true dates, your formula should work. So, can you post an image of what's in column A?

Comment: http://s12.postimg.org/a4ui1vood/Untitled5.jpg

Comment: http://s21.postimg.org/ccfnhmb9j/Untitled6.jpg

Comment: I cannot replicate the problem. The formula works. Are you sure you have Calculation set to Automatic?

Comment: I dont think so. How do i do change it. I'm in Excel 2013. I am googling now as well to see if this will fix the problem

Comment: Click on the Formulas tab of the Ribbon at the top of the Excel window. Then in the Calculation section, click on Calculation Options and make sure Automatic has the check mark.

Comment: Yeah it is set to automatic. And I just installed this Excel yesterday as well

Comment: http://s28.postimg.org/t56s5c6p9/Untitled7.jpg   A picture of my settings just to show

Comment: Make a copy before doing this... What happens if you copy column B and then paste special back to column B as values only?

Comment: I did that found out something the date actually contains "10/18/2015  8:00:00 AM" the 8AM stays the same.  So how do i do  =COUNTIF(A:A,"="&TODAY()"8:00:00 AM")

Comment: To say countif A:A =TODAY and this Text

Comment: If you are sure you want to check for exactly 8:00 AM on today's date, then you can  do this:  `=COUNTIF(A:A,"="&TODAY()+8/24)`

Comment: worked thank you! you are awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please reference the comments below the OP question.

The problem was that the dates were displayed with a number format that did not reveal there was a time component as well.

The time component was 8:00 AM.

The following formula solved the issue:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"="&TODAY()+8/24)
```